# Retrieve users having all of the groups from an array of groups with Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I have an app in which users have many groups and groups have many users, through a GroupUsers join table.

I'd like to get all the Users in **exactly all** of the groups of a given array of groups.

It sounds quite simple, yet I've not managed to find a way to do it.

This is what I tried (`all_groups` is the array of groups) :

```
users = User
all_groups.each do |group| 
  users = users.joins(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id = ?", group.id)
end
```

I always get no result, so I tried this to understand what's going on :

```
users = User

group1 = all_groups.first 
group2 = all_groups.last 

users1 = users.joins(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id = ?", group1.id)
users2 = users1.joins(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id = ?", group2.id)
```

`users1` is an array with all the users in `group1` as expected, but `users2` is always empty.

Does someone have a clue about how to solve this ?

**EDIT** : Answer :

```
users = User
all_groups.each do |group| 
  users = User.including_ids(users.map(&:id)).joins(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id = ?", group.id)
end
```

With in models/user.rb :

```
scope :including_ids, ->(*ids) {
  where(arel_table[:id].in(ids))
}
```

That's not really beautiful but it's working.

Comment: It's very simple to do by writing your own sql.  Also, you don't want to run individual queries inside your loop.  The query should include "group_id in (list of id's)"

Comment: @DanBracuk I want the users that are in exactly all the groups of the `groups` array, not the ones that are in at least one.

Comment: I mean, `IN (a,b)` is like `(IN a) OR (IN b)`, but what I want is something that is like `(IN a) AND (IN b)`.

Answer (score 0):

based on the explanation you gave, I assume you have something like:

```
class User
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users
end

class GroupUser
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, through: :group_users
end
```

If yes, you can probably do the following:

```
# get groups
groups = Group.where( ......some condition here ) 

# as long as groups is an ActiveRecord::Relation type you can use 'pluck'
User.joins( :group_users ).where( 'group_users.group_id IN (?)', groups.pluck(:id) ).uniq
```

Hope that helps. :)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help, you're totally right about the model, but that's not what I was looking for.
If groups = (A,B,C), with your answer I would retrieve users in (A and B), or (A), as I only want users in (A and B and C).